# Identify Blue Flowers

Tags: identification, wildflowers

I have pretty flowers growing outside in my yard, but I don't know what they are.

Video on Instagram: https://www.instagram.com/p/BiWzE9xHtHx/

Violets seem close, but... not quite.

One Facebook friend commented and said they look like Blue Boys, but that appears to be a slang name for any number of flowers.

[image: buds]

[image: full1]

[image: full2]

[image: full3]

[image: stalk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Tradescantia andersoniana, common name spiderwort, a hardy, herbaceous, perennial, clump forming plant. Copes well in shady areas, though it may produce fewer flowers, but prefers fertile soil http://www.bethchatto.co.uk/s-z/tradescantia/tradescantia-andersoniana-zwanenburg-blue.htm